# Crossword clues to find a single word

Tags: cryptic-clues

**Across**

First port is always just one colour
Anger in mother, in her back
First realm's emperor decorated stop sign

**Down**

Back in the water if it's a tree
Rage found in wires
Read without a single colour

**The answer is a single word.**

> I'm guessing the clues will be quite easy for our crossword gurus, so I'm omitting the line numbers and enumerations for now. I'll add them later if this goes unsolved for a while.

Comment: So, to clarify because of the tags, are some of these cryptic clues and others regular crossword clues?

Comment: @ThePuzzlingPlatypus No, they're cryptic clues (which are a special type of crossword clues). I'm not a fan of the set of tags we have for this - never quite clear which one(s) to use.

Comment: The [x-crosswords] tags are specifically for full crosswords; the [crossword-clues] tag is specifically for noncryptics. The four tags are distinct.

Comment: I know the difference, it just wasn't obvious which ones they were since you used all 4.

Comment: @Deusovi This one is a full crossword. Although possibly the fact that it is one might be considered a hint ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single word is

> FIRED

because the answers to the clues are

> ```
> FIR
> IRE
> RED
> ```

Explanations for the wordplay:

> 1a. "Port" (i.e., left) side of FIRST; a fir tree is *evergreen*, hence "always just one colour". (Thanks to msh210 for figuring this one out in comments; it was clear what it had to be because of the Down clues, but I couldn't make sense of the clue. I don't see that either part is an actual definition...) 2a. Reversed substring in "mothER In her". 3a. Initial letters of Realm, Emperor's, Decorated.
>  1d. Reversed substring in "wateR IF". 2d. Substring in wIREs. 3d. READ without A.

Comment: There, I thought this would be easy for the crossword gurus :-) If nobody gets 1a by tomorrow, I'll leave another comment with a hint, but the full answer is of course correct.

Comment: 1a is confusing me a lot because I can't make _either_ definition _or_ wordplay work, but even without your confirmation it seems clear that it has to be what I said it is.

Comment: I guess you must be right. I confess I don't much care for either half of that, but no matter :-).

Comment: Yeah, I did wonder if the definition part of 1a might have been naughty. Would something like "First port is a tree" have been better?

Comment: It would have been sounder. (In case anyone's wondering, my "I guess you must be right" comment is a reply to a comment by msh210 that he's now deleted.)